# How to get value from service.getDistanceMatrix({..........})

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a function

> calcDistance()

that calculate and show the route from place a to place b using googlemaps.
Inside calcDistance there are service.getDistanceMatrix (what this called? a function?) Inside it there are callback function when the request is complete.
Inside that function callback I want to return testres to input to result like
`result = calcDistance();`

```
    function calcDistance(origin1,destinationB){
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        var temp_duration = 0;
        var temp_distance = 0;
        var testres;
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
            {
                origins: [origin1],
                destinations: [destinationB],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function(response, status) {
                if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                    alert('Error was: ' + status);
                    testres= {"duration":0,"distance":0};
                } else {
                    var originList = response.originAddresses;
                    var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
                    var showGeocodedAddressOnMap = function (asDestination) {
                        testres= function (results, status) {
                        };
                    };
                    var duration_total;
                    for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
                        var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                        geocoder.geocode({'address': originList[i]},
                            showGeocodedAddressOnMap(false));
                        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                            geocoder.geocode({'address': destinationList[j]},
                                showGeocodedAddressOnMap(true));
                            temp_duration+=results[j].duration.value;
                            temp_distance+=results[j].distance.value;
                        }
                    }
                    testres= {"duration":temp_duration,"distance":temp_distance};
                }
            }
        );
    }

    result = calcDistance(source,dest);
</script>
```

Thankyou for reading my question. I'm sorry I give so many code to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this `service.getDistanceMatrix()` must be an `async` code which might take some time to get the result back so traditional way of returning result from function like `result = calcDistance();` won't work. Instead of that you can pass callback function which can be invoked in callback function of  `service.getDistanceMatrix` as follows:

```
function calcDistance(origin1,destinationB,ref_Callback_calcDistance){
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        var temp_duration = 0;
        var temp_distance = 0;
        var testres;
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
            {
                origins: [origin1],
                destinations: [destinationB],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
                avoidHighways: false,
                avoidTolls: false
            }, function(response, status) {
                if (status !== google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                    alert('Error was: ' + status);
                    testres= {"duration":0,"distance":0};
                } else {
                    var originList = response.originAddresses;
                    var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
                    var showGeocodedAddressOnMap = function (asDestination) {
                        testres= function (results, status) {
                        };
                    };
                    var duration_total;
                    for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
                        var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                        geocoder.geocode({'address': originList[i]},
                            showGeocodedAddressOnMap(false));
                        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                            geocoder.geocode({'address': destinationList[j]},
                                showGeocodedAddressOnMap(true));
                            temp_duration+=results[j].duration.value;
                            temp_distance+=results[j].distance.value;
                        }
                    }
                    testres= {"duration":temp_duration,"distance":temp_distance};

                    if(typeof ref_Callback_calcDistance === 'function'){
                        //calling the callback function
                        ref_Callback_calcDistance(testres)
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }

function Callback_calcDistance(testres) {
    //do something with testres
}


    //calling the calcDistance function and passing callback function reference
    calcDistance(source,dest,Callback_calcDistance);
```